# Use X forwarding for SSH server inside Docker container

Tags: ssh, xorg, docker

I'm trying to use X forwarding via SSH to run GUI apps installed in a Ubuntu-based Docker container, but X forwarding isn't applied even I installed `xauth` with `X11Forwarding yes` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. (`$DISPLAY` isn't defined.)
I tried to use X forwarding for real computers with the same configuration, and it worked well. (`$DISPLAY` is defined.)
Is X forwarding via SSH to Docker container really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the container is on your local machine it's easier to give the programs insider your container direct access to your X11 socket. For this you only need to mount `/tmp/.X11-unix` and `~/.Xauthority` into your container and set `$DISPLAY`.

Assuming you use `some_user` with home dir `/home/some_user/` to run `your_program`  in container `some_image` use

```
docker run  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
            -v ~/.Xauthority:/home/some_user/.Xauthority \
            --env DISPLAY=:0 --user some_user some_image your_program
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: After getting information from various sources as well as this post, I got two scripts to create a working setup for running nvidia jetpack inside a container. See [superuser SO "Run JetPack TX2 Installer in a Docker Container"](https://superuser.com/a/1323124/71757)